Telebot | Как поставить кнопки в один ряд если они в IF
Мне нужно поставить кнопки в один ряд, но они выходят в столбик, я пробовал добавить row, но из-за IF все портится и не получается определить. Буду благодарен за помощь.
# Функция для отправки списка игроков по частям с кнопками навигации
    def send_players_in_batches(chat_id, players, page_number, message_id=None):
        players_per_page = 1
        start_index = (page_number - 1) * players_per_page
        end_index = start_index + players_per_page
        current_players = players[start_index:end_index]

        message_text = "✦ <b>Список игроков в чате</b> ✦\n\n"
        for player in current_players:
            message_text += f"✧ <b>{player['username']}</b> - {player['nick']}\n"

        # Создаем клавиатуру с кнопками "Назад" и "Вперед"
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        if page_number > 1:
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️", callback_data=f"list_page_{page_number - 1}")
            keyboard.row(btn1)
        if end_index < len(players):
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("➡️", callback_data=f"list_page_{page_number + 1}")

        if message_id:
            # Редактируем уже существующее сообщение
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id, text=message_text,
                                  parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)
        else:
            # Отправляем новое сообщение
            bot.send_message(chat_id, message_text, parse_mode="HTML", reply_markup=keyboard)


Вместо добавления кнопки прямо после условного оператора if, Вы можете создать пустой список и добавлять туда кнопки по срабатыванию условия, а затем добавить в клавиатуру все кнопки из этого списка в один ряд keyboard.row(*buttons_list)
